parsing XMLs on TCL?
I am trying to iterate and print XML in TCL, and later make it an array. I am importing xml,libxml12,dom, and then parsing the xml content. then I've tried documentElement to start iterating, but it fails:
bad method "documentElement": must be cget, configure, createElement, createDocumentFragment, createTextNode, createComment, createCDATASection, createProcessingInstruction, createAttribute, createEntity, createEntityReference, createDocTypeDecl, importNode, createElementNS, createAttributeNS, getElementsByTagNameNS, getElementsById, createEvent, getElementsByTagName, dtd, or schema

    while executing
"$document documentElement"

Are there other methods?
Nothing I saw online works for me.
That is my current code:
#!/usr/intel/bin/tclsh8.6
package require xml
package require xml::libxml2
package require dom

# Specify the path to your XML file
set xmlFile "BLA BLA BLA"
# Check if the file exists
if {[file exists $xmlFile]} {

    set xmlH [open $xmlFile "r"]
    set xml [read $xmlH]
    # # Parse the XML content
    set document [dom::parse $xml]
    set root [$document documentElement]


} else {
    puts "Error: XML file not found at $xmlFile"
}


I'd normally use tdom to parse XML...

my bad, this is the correct way:
set root [$document cget -documentElement]

